# Why am I getting the "list index out of range" error?

Tags: python, indexoutofboundsexception

This is my program:

```
   def FoundmovieNamesInQuery(userQueryPart,nameOfMovie):
        for userQueryPart in userQuery:
            for nameOfMovie in movieNames:
                if userQueryPart == nameOfMovie:
                    return True
        return False


    print("welcome")
    userQuery = input("use our quick search to find cinema times for films shwing today: ").lower().split()
    print(userQuery)

    with open("movies.txt")as file:
        lines = file.readline()
    slutionFound = False

    for line in lines:
        item = line.split(":")
        movieNames = item[0].split()
        movieTimes = item[1]
        if FoundmovieNamesInQuery():
            print(movieTimes)
            solutionFound = True
    if solutionFound == False:
        print("movie not found.\n please call us on 0800 020 030")
```

But it gives the following error message when I run it:

```
welcome
use our quick search to find cinema times for films shwing today: annabelle
['annabelle']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FARUQE TALUKDAR\Downloads\online film.py", line 20, in <module>
    movieTimes = item[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is my text file:

```
run along : this movie will be showing at 18.00
annabelle : this movie will be showing at 13.00
x-men : this movie will be showing at 7.00
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be lines = file.readlines() ?

Comment: WOW that actually worked . Thanks!

Comment: such a simple mistake but made my headache for days

Comment: Even a beginner programmer should be able to figure out simple bugs such as this one by using divide and conquer and `print(item)` debugging . Here's a basic guide to debugging. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: In this case I suspect that you have a `line` that doesn't contain any `:` character. So your `split` returns a list containing a single string.

Comment: @HåkenLid Sometimes you just go blind, there is no remedy for that.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to use `readlines` instead of using `readline`, it will read the whole txt.

Second, you need to pass parameters to the funtion `FoundmovieNamesInQuery(userQuery, movieNames)`.

```
def FoundmovieNamesInQuery(userQueryPart,nameOfMovie):
        for userQueryPart in userQuery:
            for nameOfMovie in movieNames:
                if userQueryPart == nameOfMovie:
                    return True
        return False


print("welcome")
userQuery = input("use our quick search to find cinema times for films shwing today: ").lower().split()
print(userQuery)

with open("movies.txt")as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
solutionFound = False

for line in lines:
    item = line.split(":")
    movieNames = item[0].split()
    movieTimes = item[1]
    if FoundmovieNamesInQuery(userQuery, movieNames):
        print(movieTimes)
        solutionFound = True
if solutionFound == False:
    print("movie not found.\n please call us on 0800 020 030")
```